# How to make this HTTP Post request using alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, http, curl, alamofire

How to use alamofire with the given sample?

> curl -X POST "http://localhost:2202/api/project" -H "accept:
>   aplication/json" -H "key: David" -H "Content-Type:
>   multipart/form-data" -F "project={"title":"Test
>   Title","description":"Test description for new
>   project","priority":false,"category_id":1,"location_id":1}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let url = "192.168.1.1/api/project"
var header = [String:String]()
header["accept"] = "aplication/json"
header["key"] = "David"
let reqParam = ["project":["title":"Test Title","description":"Test description for new project","priority":false,"category_id":1,"location_id":1]]
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    for (key, value) in reqParam{
        do{
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: .prettyPrinted)
             multipartFormData.append(data, withName: key)
        }catch(let err){
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
},usingThreshold:UInt64.init(),
  to: url,
  method: .post,
  headers: ["Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"],
  encodingCompletion: { (result) in
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, the Swift compailer says: Cannot call value of non-function type 'String', Value of type '[String : Any]' has no member 'data' in line 8, what to do now?

Comment: What is your advice?

Comment: Use local ip instead of localhost

Comment: i use my local ip, here is a screenshot, what is your oppinion?

Comment: https://ibb.co/y869khS

Comment: I hope you got solution.

Comment: Dear Shivang Pandey, you are amazing, can you help me one more time?

Comment: Thankx,Just raise question on stackoverflow ,i'll replay.

Comment: i think you are taking about this question : - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57042150/9697632